# words count example in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, associative-array

I see a lot of Scala tutorials with examples doing things like recrursive traversals or solving math problems. In my daily programming life I have the feeling most of my coding time is spent on mundane tasks like string manipulation, database queries and date manipulations. Is anyone interested to give an example of the a Scala version of the following perl script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
#opens a file with on each line one word and counts the number of occurrences 
# of each word, case insensitive
print "Enter the name of your file, ie myfile.txt:\n";
my $val = <STDIN>;
chomp ($val);
open (HNDL, "$val") || die "wrong filename";

my %count = ();
while ($val = <HNDL>)
{
        chomp($val);
    $count{lc $val}++;
}
close (HNDL);

print "Number of instances found of:\n";
foreach my $word (sort keys %count) {
        print "$word\t: " . $count{$word} . " \n";
}
```

In summary:

- ask for a filename
- read the file (contains 1 word per line)
- do away with line ends  ( cr, lf or crlf)
- lowercase the word
- increment count of the word
- print out each word, sorted alphabetically, and its count

TIA

Comment: Have you tried to search? I've found a couple of examples, right on the first page of "scala word count" google search results.

Comment: http://www.scalanlp.org/ contains text processing tools.

Answer (score 10):

A simple word count like that could be written as follows:

```
import io.Source
import java.io.FileNotFoundException

object WC {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Enter the name of your file, ie myfile.txt:")
    val fileName = readLine

    val words = try {
      Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toSeq.map(_.toLowerCase.trim)
    } catch {
      case e: FileNotFoundException =>
        sys.error("No file named %s found".format(fileName))
    }

    val counts = words.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

    println("Number of instances found of:")
    for((word, count) <- counts) println("%s\t%d".format(word, count))

  }

}
```

Comment: thanks drexin, just what i wanted to see. so scala is not too verbose too.

Comment: It's not only not verbose but also not encrypted!

Answer (score 3):

If you're going for concise/compact, you can in 2.10:

```
// Opens a file with one word on each line and counts
// the number of occurrences of each word (case-insensitive)
object WordCount extends App {
  println("Enter the name of your file, e.g. myfile.txt: ")
  val lines = util.Try{ io.Source.fromFile(readLine).getLines().toSeq } getOrElse
    { sys.error("Wrong filename.") }
  println("Number of instances found of:")
  lines.map(_.trim.toLowerCase).toSeq.groupBy(identity).toSeq.
    map{ case (w,ws) => s"$w\t: ${ws.size}" }.sorted.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: wow rex, that's compact indeed. more so than the perl original (though that was not written esp. for compactness). sorted too. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  val lines : List[String] = List("this is line one" , "this is line 2", "this is line three")

  val linesConcat : String = lines.foldRight("")( (a , b) => a + " "+ b)

  linesConcat.split(" ").groupBy(identity).toList.foreach(p => println(p._1+","+p._2.size))
```

prints :

```
this,3
is,3
three,1
line,3
2,1
one,1
```